# ionic 3 get current location not working on android phone

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

My ionic 3 application tries to get the currentlocation by using Geolocation from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx'.

When i rum my app in android phone,getLoc() is getting called but getCurrentPosition() method is not getting called.

```
getLoc() {

    alert('getLoc');
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      resp.coords.latitude
      resp.coords.longitude
      alert('inside then');
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting location', error);
       alert('catch');
     });

  }
```

Comment: Please show us how you call your function getLoc

Comment: @Mehdi actually it is a click function.

 `<button ion-button (click)="getLoc()">Get current LatLong</button>`

Comment: so this getLoc function is declared in the component responsible for this click? Share both html and ts files please

Comment: yeah yeah..

this is the ts file function

`this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
        alert("asdasd")
      }).catch( (err) => {
        alert('error is here');
      });`

this is the html part..


`<button ion-button (click)="getLoc()">Get current LatLong</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct import for ionic 3 is :

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

try to change the import, if it don't work , downgrade the geolocation plugin version.

Comment: no mate, that does not work either. When i change the import according to your way,  `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` require 3 arguments and it does not work as a promise.

Comment: Ionic 3 don't have ngx import , you need to downgrade your plugin version.

Comment: yes.. my code is working now. I did change the import by removing "/ngx".
Thank you